# Is there a Dikk-like application for Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, screen-capture, screen-sharing

There is an application for Mac OS X called *[Dikk](http://www.binarynights.com/dikk)* that allows one to capture its screen and send it to another user who installed Dikk by simply hitting a key. Is there any similar application for Linux?

I know, I can setup VNC, but I'm looking for a solution that let me *push* my screen to another user while VNC only allows me to *pull* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that every unix should have on it already is xwd & xwud.  You could make a script to perform this function for you, then bind the script to a function key.  In gnome this script might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash


set ans=`Xdialog --title "Dikk-let" \
       --inputbox "Push a screen shot to who?" 10 50`

xwd -root | xwud -display ${ans}:0.0
```

The script prompts you to type an ip address or host name to send a picture of your root display to someone.  If you enter nothing, the screen displays on your machine.

This assumes you have Xdialog installed, i.e.  `sudo apt-get xdialog`

I named my script "dikk" and saved it in a directory where I put little scripts like this -> ~/bin.  Given that, you can add a custom from System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts

[image: gnome keyboard shortcut example]