# Defining keyboard shorcuts for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, keyboard-shortcuts

I just installed Ubuntu 9.10 on my PC.Can I define keyboard shortcuts for various application or places in it?

This question arose in my mind because- I am using the terminal frequently.So everytime I have to go the menu "Applications"->"Accessories"->"Terminal"

So it becomes tedious by each time.

So do you know any or other way to define keyboard shortcuts for such Ubuntu places/apps?
(Or at least for terminal)

EDIT : What I actual want is,suppose if I press some key, say ~ ,the terminal should pop out from top and on pressing ` again it should go back.I've seen it somewhere and it makes life simpler with terminal.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts

"Open a Terminal Window" is under "Desktop"

Comment: Also refer to http://superuser.com/questions/46790/is-there-a-dikk-like-application-for-linux for a description of how to associate a keyboard shortcut with a script that you write.

Answer (score 2):

System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts

This will work for most of the default actions. If you want to add a keyboard shortcut for something that is not listed there, you can [create custom keyboard shortcuts using this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/).

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT : What I actual want is,suppose if I press some key, say ~ ,the terminal should pop out from top and on pressing ` again it should go back.I've seen it somewhere and it makes life simpler with terminal.

You are probably searching for a terminal like [tilda](http://tilda.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Install using the usual:

```
sudo apt-get install tilda
```

and then, always from the command line, launch

```
tilda -C
```

to configure the program. Then start it in the background with

```
nohup tilda &
```

From now on you can use the F1 key to reveal and hide the terminal.

Remember that every time you restart the PC, you have to manually restart tilda, otherwise you can add tilda to the list of applications that run automatically at startup (follow for example [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup) instructions).

Alternatively, if you don't like the idea of installing a new terminal, you can use the default gnome keyboard shortcuts to minimize the active (Alt-F9) window and focus the last active window (Alt-Tab).

Look [here](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/windows-manipulating.html.en) for more informations on how to control the windows.

Comment: Ok I was looking for the same thing you are talking about.
Now I have downloaded it.But being new to linux, don't know how to apply/run it.

Can you please help me out on how to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [YaKuake](http://yakuake.kde.org/): a very nice terminal that drops down from the screen top, highly customizable and newb-friendly. Enjoy :)